# Why '1.66' does not match 1.66 in MySQL in double-field?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I wondered, why my queries formed in Perl code using DBI did not returned correct records. I had simple queries like :

```
my $query = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE title = ? AND price = ?";
```

I executed it like:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $query );
my ($id) = $dbh->selectcol_arrayref( $sth, undef, $title, $price );
```

Most time everything worked fine but in some rare cases i did not get results i expected. So i tried from CLI too. Fulled query with dubious values:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE title = 'Some title' AND price = 1.66;
```

And got desired records back. After that i **quoted** price value too:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE title = 'Some title' AND price = '1.66';
```

And got **zero** records as result.

After that I tried with other quoted price values, like '1.67' and they worked fine.

What is problem here? Why such simple queries fail? To reproduce behaviour i put simple schema and query up to [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/b7847/7/0), As you may see simple query `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE price = '1.66' OR price = '1.67';` gives only one result.

I feel, it may be related to the nature of double datatype (1.66 is represented as 1.66666666... ?), but how should i form then my queries, when i use placeholders in DBI?

Comment: Why use a double for a price instead of a DECIMAL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should never compare floating point numbers for equality. You should use a tolerance. Either use a tolerance or switching from floating point numbers (to `numeric`, `text` or cents in an `integer`).

Comment: And where were my eyes? Used certainly too much doubles so far. Thank you!